# Broadcast Receiver is not working at first app startup

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

`BroadcastReceiver` Class in not working at app first startup. I want to check the internet connection simultaneously also at app startup. Please help with the issue.

```
NetworkchangeListener.Java 

public class NetworkChangeListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static boolean isNetworkConnected= false ;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    isNetworkConnected = isNetworkAvailable(context);
    if(isNetworkConnected){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

}

Below is my Manifest.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dcastalia.clienttest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeListener">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It's working fine when i change the network state but for the first runtime it's doesn't working.

Comment: It's working as expected. Because you added intent filters.Please change the intent filters

Comment: why he should change the intent-filter if it exactly what he wants? I guess the main problem is (I had this too), that on some devices (for example Huawei), you have to open your app by pressing the icon first before a receiver works. I don´t know what´s the intention behind that, maybe a bug...

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast receiver would be executed only on CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE as added in intent-filters.To check internet connection on app start up,you can refer link below [How to check if internet is available or not in app startup in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194192/how-to-check-if-internet-is-available-or-not-in-app-startup-in-android)

Comment: I want to get the connection status continuously on App startup and app running state also. I don't want to check it for one time.